# Why is my Timer not Triggering for a while after subscription?

Tags: c#, events, timer, event-handling, handler

I have a Timer (System.Timers.Timer) that triggers every 100ms.

I subscribe an Event Handler to the Timer and it works just fine:

```
  public override void TimerEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (timerlock)
        {
            Timer.Stop();
            ...
            Timer.Start();
        }
    }
```

I use the timerlock, so when I unsubscribe from the timer I can be sure I am not in the middle of my TimerEvent Method.

So then when I want to unsubscribe from the Timer I do this:

```
    lock (timerlock)
    {
        Timer.Elapsed -= TimerEvent;
    }
    try
    {
       DoSomethingThatTakesUpToAMinute();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)            
    {
        MessageBox.Show("...");
    }
    finally
    {
        Timer.Elapsed += TimerEvent;
    }
```

But when I subscribe to the Timer again in the finally block, my program takes up to 15 seconds until the next timer Event is registered even tho the finally was already executed. Note that what I do between unsubsribing and resubscribing to the timer can take up to a Minute.

I can see in the console that there are About 5 Threads that end with error Code 0 after the finally block and once they all ended my TimerEvents are Triggered again.

Any ideas?